# Is it possible to have a logoutUrl and a route with the same url in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

currently I'm writing an spring boot cloud gateway application to act as a proxy to my microservices.

Also I'm using spring security with oauth2 schema in my microservices and my gateway.(some thing like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2#1-spring-cloud-gateway-as-an-oauth-20-client).)

My microservice has a default logout URL and logout handler.(I know little about its implementation since it has been developed by another team before the time I started to write the gateway for it.), It works fine now and clients call this URL (probably with some parameters) and they will be logged out.

Now I want to have a logout mechanism in my gateway to completely log the user out of both gateway and my microservice.(e.g.: clear tokens and security context, invalidate cache or anything necessary )

my attempt: I had an idea to have a common URL that act simultaneously as a route in my gateway(so we can call this URL as before from clients as before(with a little change in url called from clients actually) and will be forwarded to the logout endpoint of our microservice) and a logout URL in my gateway( so I can Add some Logout handlers to invalidate session, clear Oauth tokens from  gateway token repository, clear security context holder , ...)

But I don't know whether it is possible or not or even if there exists another fine solution to my problem.

Comment: you wanti to add logout mechanism in your gateway?  it sound weird

Comment: I don't think so. Only one thing in a boot app can handle a unique path

Answer (score 0):

You don't "logout" from resource servers (REST APIs secured with access tokens like your micro services behind the gateway probably are). No more than you "login" to it. Login and logout are OAuth2 clients concern.

The gateway might be configured as an OAuth2 client (with login and logout) when used between Javascript based applications (Angular, React, Vue, etc.). It is even a recommanded pattern (Backend For Frontend) if you use the TokenRelay filter: requests to the gateway are secured with a session cookie and gateway replaces the session cookie with an access token it keeps in session before forwarding requests to resource servers.

In short, no logout from resource servers. Logout is performed by OAuth2 client, which the gateway might be if it is configured as an OAuth2 client (and only in that case is it concerned with login or logout).